# Gitlab pages 401 error when adding custom domain with Namecheap

Tags: permissions, gitlab, http-status-code-401, namecheap, gitlab-pages

After getting the site running on `https://*username*.gitlab.io/*project name*/` I tried adding a custom domain. The domain is fitshapeprogressions.com.
But this results in the following error:

[image: 1]

I set the pages to access control to 'everyone' so why would there be a permission error?

[image: 2]

I set things up as follows.

For the DNS site of things I followed this explanation: [401 error when adding custom domain to gitlab pages](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9645/2208/how-do-i-link-my-domain-to-github-pages/)
Ending with these settings:

[image: 3]

On the GitLab site of things the domain got successfully verified

[image: 4]

I've looked at similar problems but proposed solutions don't seem to work https://forum.gitlab.com/t/401-unauthorized-error-for-gitlab-page-deployed-with-publii/37180/6

401 Unauthorized error for GitLab page deployed with Public
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/401-error-when-adding-custom-domain-to-gitlab-pages/30517 401 error when adding a custom domain to GitLab pages

Any ideas as to what might be causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also asked this question on the gitlab forums and the solution was provided.

Solution:
The txt records were pointing to the wrong domain and had to be changed according to documentation. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/#3-set-up-dns-records-for-pages

Solution link:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/401-error-when-adding-custom-domain-to-gitlab-pages-with-namecheap/50267